# Remove Background HTML5-Video/WEBVTT subtitle on iOS iPhone/iPad

Tags: html, video, background, subtitle, webvtt

I have a HTML5 video with a track-element for subtitles in webvtt-format.
How can I remove the black background behind the subtitles on iOS/iPhone/iPad?
In the browsers on a PC I can remove it with CSS ::cue{background: transparent;}

Thanks for help

Comment: have you tried to use any jquery Player ? For example JW Player. @Baumi

Answer (score 2):

I think i found the solution. It took me couple of days and a lot of Googling, to finally figure it.

It has got to do with MacOS(iOS) System Preferences, and how to show captions.

To fix this, go to:

Mac System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Captions -> Change "Transparent Background" to "Classic".

You will have to close the browser tab or application, for it to apply.
I discovered that the subtitles in the HTML player were without the background until the next morning, because I hadn't closed the tab before.

Had I changed the setting back, I wouldn't have found it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Safari uses -webkit-media-text-track-display-backdrop for it's background color. Note the !important which overrides Safari's inherent styling.

```
video::-webkit-media-text-track-display-backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
video::-webkit-media-text-track-display{background-color: transparent;}
```

On IOS7 it works correctly.

Comment: Can you send me a complete example for html and css file?